# How to create an array of objects having values as objects from an array that has been created in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, map-function

I have an array whose elements are in string format, like this:

```
somearray = [object, object, object]
```

where each object has a

```
fname: "abc", lname: "pqr", age: 31
```

I am trying to create an object from this array whose variable I have declared as var newobject = {}. I tried this:

```
newobject = somearray.map(function(x) {
  return {
    fname: x.fname,
    lname: x.lname,
    age: x.age
  };
});
```

This does create an object of the format [object, object, object] where each object is

```
fname: "abc", lname: "pqr", age: 31
```

What I desire to achieve is 'fname' and 'lname' should be objects as in the following

```
fname: object, lname: object, age: 31
```

What are the modifications I will need to make? Where the fname and lname objects will be:

```
fname: {firstname: "abc"}
```

And I am doing this because in later part of the program I will be adding more properties to fname and lname.

Comment: What kind of object should `fname` and `lname` be?

Comment: What will be the properties for fname and lname objects?

Comment: create a fiddle or plunker to resolve the issue

Comment: Those two should be like: fname: {fname: "abc"} and lname: {lname: "pqr"}

Comment: You don’t need `newobject = {}`. It’s not going to be a plain object, anyway. You can always write that `return` statement as `return {fname: {fname: "abc"}, lname: {lname: "pqr"}, age: x.age};`. Not really sure where your problem is.

Comment: *Those two should be like: `fname: {fname: "abc"}`* Then put that in your question.

Comment: @torazaburo Thanks for the suggestion :) I've put it there

Comment: @Xufox That's what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your map function like

```
  var newobject = somearray.map(function(x) {
      return {
          fname: {
              fname: x.fname
          },
          lname: {
              lname: x.lname
          },
          age: x.age
      };
  });
```

Comment: @Ad33 May I ask what the reason for this requirement is? Why would you nest an object property in an object as the property of the same name? In other words: you’d need to access the value as `somearray[`…`].fname.fname` as opposed to as simply `somearray[`…`].fname` — why do you want this?

Comment: @Xufox I have mentioned the same name here, although its not. And in the late part of the program I add more properties to this object. That's why I needed it this way. Thanks though :)